# Can C# use Firefox instead of IE for Webforms?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, coldfusion

I have a bit of a problem.  I use a front end application written in C# for my companies order entry, quotes, contracts, and to control printing.  It also uses a built in web browser to access ColdFusion (8) web forms.  The latest IE patch is leaving users who updated their IE to be unable to click links from within the application.

I can either:

- Reinstall an older version of IE which works
- Re-write the web-browser to possibly use another browser as it's base. I've                       never done this so I'm clueless.

Am I on the correct path? What I have them doing now is just opening the application from Chrome and it works great; however, there are some fuctons that call back to the C# application that do not work when using an external browser.

Comment: Do you know why they cannot click the links? It may just be a security or advanced option that needs to be enabled in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the underlying cause isn't immediately obvious you could attempt to specify for internet explorer to use its older version via the x-ua header.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj676915.aspx

If this works it can be a good fix to buy time to resolve the underlying cause of the problem but don't stay on the old version of internet explorer if you can. These problems will only get worse going forward and you'll miss out on the improvements to internet explorer if you do.

Comment: We used this solution recently in a situation where some javascript stopped working properly after browser upgrades.

Comment: This works for me, thank you Right now, I'm patching an old system just keeping it running for users while I build a newer system.